# How To Show Or Hide A Tablix Based On A Bit Field In SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a multi row dataset that I want to do a lookup on and take the bit/Boolean value of one of it's columns and apply it to the hidden property of a tablix.

Here is the expression for the `hidden` property on the tablix.

`= IIF(Lookup(6, Fields!ServiceOfferingID.Value, Fields!UseCustomCalculator.Value, "JobBuyerDetails") = 0, True, False)`

If the ServiceOfferingID is 6, get what is in the UseCustomCalculator column to show or hide the tablix.

I don't know if you can compare values like this, what may need to be a string or if they are all just variants.

I have tried converting the values to string with CStr(), putting quotes around the searched value (6 in this case) but have had no luck getting the tablix to show or hide correctly.

There doesn't seem to be a good way to debug this, check what the Lookup is returning etc.

How can I change my expression to get it to work?

What am I missing?

I am pretty new to SQL Server Reporting Services.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging in the traditional sense isn't really an option. What I normally do is add a textbox and set the expression to the expression you want to test, in your case, set the expression to

```
=Lookup(6, Fields!ServiceOfferingID.Value, Fields!UseCustomCalculator.Value, "JobBuyerDetails")
```

and see what you get.

Once you've established what is being returned and corrected the comparison then you can simplify the hidden expression a little.

The hidden expression would just be something like (assuming lookup issues are resolved)

=Lookup(6, Fields!ServiceOfferingID.Value, Fields!UseCustomCalculator.Value, "JobBuyerDetails") = 0

There's no need to use an `IIF` here as the comparison will return return or false anyway.